# What are the difference between Koro-sensei and other tentacle creatures?

Tags: assassination-classroom

Koro-sensei and tentacle-having humans (e.g. Itona) have a drastic difference in their bodies: Koro-sensei's body is made up of tentacles wholly, whereas Itona has his human body along with a tentacle.

Are there any differences between the no. of the tentacle cells infused? If yes, it's a fact that even a single tentacle cell can cause death like pain, then how did Koro-sensei survive that much pain?

Comment: Bonus question- Tentacles do not consume human body (eg itona) , they  form their separate organs(tentacles). Whereas , in case of Koro sensei, the body is devoured to shape a octopus tentacle made body .Where did his human body go ?

Comment: Re: your bonus question, isn't it already answered on [your own question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/43515/how-did-koro-sensei-body-change-from-humanoid-to-octopus-like-creature?rq=1)?

Comment: Thanks senpai , I understood the meaning  And thanks alot , you always help me with my queries @AkiTanaka senpai  , good to have a knowledgeable senpai like you .

Comment: Koro's tentacle changed his body because he wants to have a weak huggable body,

Answer (score 2):

The most important point is that Koro-sensei told his tentacles that he doesn't want to be powerful, so they became like they now look.

The other tentacle monsters only wanted power and told the tentacles, so their tentacles became hard and strong.

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se]. While this answer might be correct in general, could you also answer the asked questions about the no. of the tentacle cells infused? You can always [edit] to improve your post. Meanwhile, consider taking a quick [tour] to understand how this site works.